Conjectured Riemann Zeta Function Integrals, $\zeta(s)$ linked to Gregory Coefficients and convergent for $\Re(s)>0$ and $s\neq 1$
The Riemann Zeta Function $\zeta(s)$ is typically defined for complex $s$ and $\Re(s)>0$ by
$$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1}\,dx$$
where $\Gamma(s)$ is the Gamma function. (Wikipedia: Riemann zeta function)
This can be converted to a unit integral via the substitution $u\to e^{-x}$.
$$\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^1 \frac{(-\log(u))^{s-1}}{1-u}\,du=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^1 \frac{\log(1/u)^{s-1}}{1-u}\,du$$
[As was kindly pointed out to me by by @jjagmath: drawing $(-1)^{s-1}$ as a factor out from the integral is not generally correct if $s$ is complex and changes the sign of the result of integrals (1) and (2) below for $0<\Re(s)<1$]
The context of this question is an attempt to discover equations for the zeta function convergent for $0<\text{Re}(s)<1$ other than those already known, such as Dirichlet Eta function integrals and Riemann's functional integral as described on the Wikipedia page referenced above.
The conjectured integrals are based on utilizing integrals of the form:
$$f(u,s)=\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{\log(u)}+\frac{1}{1-u} \right) g(u,s)\,du\tag{1a}$$
The series expansion being
$$\left(\frac{1}{\log(u)}+\frac{1}{1-u} \right)=\frac{1}{\log(u)}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty u^n\tag{1b}$$
or alternatively via the substitution $u \to 1-v$
$$f(v,s)=\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{\log(1-v)}+\frac{1}{v} \right) g(v,s)\,dv\tag{2a}$$
The series expansion being
$$\left(\frac{1}{\log(1-v)}+\frac{1}{v} \right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \lvert G_{n+1} \rvert v^n\tag{2b}$$
where $G_n$ is the $n$th Gregory Coefficient.
If $g(u,s)=1$ then in its simplest form the above integral reduces to the well known integral for the Euler-Mascheroni constant, $\gamma$.
$$\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{\log(u)}+\frac{1}{1-u} \right) \,du=\gamma=0.577215...$$
or alternatively $g(v,s)=1$
$$\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{\log(1-v)}+\frac{1}{v} \right) \,dv=\gamma=0.577215...$$
which is equivalent to associated sum involving Gregory Coefficients Series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ \lvert G_n \rvert }{n}=\gamma$$
First Conjectured Integral convergent for $\Re(s)>0$  and $s\neq 1$:
$$\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{(s-1)\Gamma(s)}\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{\log(u)}+\frac{1}{1-u} \right) \frac{(-\log(u))^{s}}{1-u}\,du\tag{3}$$
where $\displaystyle{\lim_{s \to 1}}\,(s-1)\zeta(s)=1$
Similar Second Conjectured Integral convergent for $\Re(s)>0$  and $s\neq 1$:
$$\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{s-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{\Gamma(s-1)}\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{\log(u)}+\frac{1}{1-u} \right) (-\log(u))^{s-1}\,du \right)\tag{4}$$
where again $\displaystyle{\lim_{s \to 1}}\,(s-1)\zeta(s)=1$
(Proof only straight forward for (2) for $\Re(s)>1$. Numerical Integration appears to be convergent for $\Re(s)>0$ and $s\ne1$)
This generates series at integer values containing Gregory Coefficients $G_n$ and (generalised if needed) harmonic numbers $H_n$.
For example $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ \lvert G_n \rvert \,H_n }{n} =\frac{\pi^2}{6}-1$$ which is well known (see again Gregory Coefficients Series)
A whole raft of similar integrals can be composed, including for example, Catalan's constant and the other Dirichlet Beta Function constants.
The question is how to approach a general proof for these two conjectured Riemann Zeta Function integrals?
Update (26/06/24):
From (4) I have managed to deduce a divergent series sum for the complex values of the Riemann Zeta Function along the critical line.  It gradually converges to the start of the Zeta function (smallest values of $\sigma$ first) as more terms $t$ are added, but at the expense of an increasingly diverging function at higher values of $\sigma$. Thus it needs a ridiculous amount of numerical calculation precision to semi-converge on even the first non-trivial zero. Not really practical from a numerical calculation point of view.
$$\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+\sigma i)\approx\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{2}+\sigma i)-1}+\sum_{m=0}^t \lvert G_{m+1} \rvert \sum_{n=0}^m (-1)^n {m\choose n} (n+1)^{-(\frac{1}{2}+\sigma i)}$$

I believe there's a sign error in your first conjectured integral, i.e. your first conjectured integral would correspond to $-\zeta(s)$.

Thanks. Corrected that.

I think the second integral is much easier than I at first thought (trivial even) if I initially put aside the Gregory coefficients expansion and simply use the Geometric series for $(1-x)^{-1}$. Shows how easy it is to confuse myself unnecessarily as usual.

I'm not sure if your conjectured integral representations converge for $\Re(s)>0$ or only $\Re(s)>1$, but there are integral representations here on the Wolfram Functions site that converge for $0<\Re(s)<1$, $\Re(s)>0$, $\Re(s)>-1$, or even $s\in\mathbb{C}$.

Its not too hard to prove your second conjectured integral representation is valid for $\Re(s)>1$ using the substitution $u\to e^{-x}$, but so far I've only been able to partially evaluate your first conjectured integral representation using this substitution.

When you make the substitution you change $\log(1/u)^{s-1}$ by $\frac{1}{(-1)^{s-1}}\log(u)^{s-1}$ which is false in general for complex numbers $s$.

I'm not following you for a couple of reasons, First, that's the substitution you used in derivation of your formula following your statement "This can be converted to a unit integral via substitution". Second, there is no $\log(1/u)^{s-1}$ in either of your conjectured formulas which is the starting point for my derivations, and with respect to the substituting $u\to e^{-x}$ into $\log(u)^{s-1}$, note that $\log\left(e^{-x}\right)^{s-1}=(-x)^{s-1}=(-1)^{s-1}, x^{s-1}$ is valid for $x\ge 0$ (i.e.over the entire integration range).

I've truely messed this up. Will try a recovery operation on the post tomorrow.

Hopefully the question is more intelligible now following the revamp today.
